# React.js - How to set a default value for date input type on react.js

Tags: reactjs, date, datetime, printing

I can't print the value of "dataSubEvento" in the input.

```
**const [dataSubEvento, setDataSubEvento] = useState(
    props.activeSubEventData.data
  );
    <input
              className="createsubevent-item_input"
              onChange={(text) => setDataSubEvento(text.target.value)}
              value={dataSubEvento}
              type="date"
            >
</input>**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hujyk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlNrp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your date format is `yyyy-mm-dd` in order to display the value, and to print the value you should use the `useEffect` hook, take a look at [the complete example](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-stallman-1ie4pz?file=/src/App.js).